# Subsetting dates from colnames

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
TAS1     2000 obs. of 9862 variables
```

Each of these variables (columns) represent daily temperatures from 1979-01-01 to 2005-12-31. The colnames have been set with these dates. I now wish to separate the dataframe into twelve separate monthly data frames - containing Jan, Feb, Mar etc.

I have tried:

```
TAS1.JAN = subset(TAS1, grepl("-01-"), colnames(TAS1))
```

But get the error:

```
Error in grepl("-01-") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a relatively quick solution for this? I feel there must be but haven't cracked it despite trying various solutions.

Comment: `grepl` takes at least 2 arguments: `grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)`. The pattern that you look for `"-01"` and the datas in which you cant to look for it.

Comment: I'd melt to long format ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subset January data like below.

```
Jan_df <- subset(MyDatSet, select=(grepl("-01-, colnames(MyDatSet))))
```

I have assumed that your parent dataset is called MyDatSet and a pattern "-01-" defines that it is January data.
You may repeat the process for other 11 months or come up with intelligent loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like Roland, in the comments, suggested, I would opt for melting mechanism too. However, since I do not know your use case, here you go based on what you posted and asked for.

As your error says, you are missing an argument there:

```
tas1.jan <- subset(df, grepl("-01-", df$tas1))
```

Another way to do it with the help of stringr and dplyr would be:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

tas1.jan <-  df %>% filter(str_detect(tas1, "-01-"))
```

Bottom side of this approach: you need to run a loop or do this 12 times for all months.

Comment: Thanks - this does work but takes rather a long time. The suggestion below appears to work much more quickly.